# Generate the product variations SKUs from Woocommerce parent variable SKU

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations, sku

In WooCommerce I would like to generate the product variations SKUs from the parent variable product SKU like:

- Variable Product sku: 1200
- 1st Product Variation SKU: 1200-01
- 2nd Product Variation SKU: 1200-02
- 3rd Product Variation SKU: 1200-03
- *… and so on …*

So I need an SKU in the order (and shown on the product page when choosing the variation). For example, 1200-01

I can not figure out how to achieve that in WooCommerce. I worked with other shop systems before and this was a very basic setting to get the variations running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple ways to generate a combined SKU for product variations from the parent variable product. Here are two of them:

**1st way:**

The following code will just generate for front end display ("view") a combined sku when the product uses the WC_Product method `get_sku()` *(but will not generate and save combined variation SKUs from the variable product like in the other way)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sku', 'custom_variation_sku', 10, 3 );
function custom_variation_sku( $sku, $product ) {

    if( $main_sku = get_post_meta( $product->get_parent_id(), '_sku', true ) ){
        $sku = $main_sku . '-' . sprintf( '%02d', ( get_post($product->get_id())->menu_order ) );
    }

    return $sku;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### 2nd way:

The following will auto generate the product variations SKUs from the variable product SKU.

The first function will add a checkbox to the variable product settings in **"Advanced"** tab. **Only when you will check this checkbox**, the 2nd function will generate all the product variations SKUs from the variable product SKU.

```
// Custom checkbox for auto generation of the variations SKUs
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_advanced', 'additional_product_options_advanced_custom_checkbox');
function additional_product_options_advanced_custom_checkbox()
{
    global $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group show_if_variable hidden">';

    // Custom checkbox located on Advanced tab settings
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(
        'id'          => 'generate_variations_skus',
        'label'       => __('Generate variations SKUs', 'woocommerce'),
        'description' => __('Auto Generation of the variations SKUs from variable sku', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true'
    ));

    echo '</div>';
}

// Auto generate the variations SKUs
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'wc_auto_generate_variations_skus', 10, 1 );
function wc_auto_generate_variations_skus( $product ) {

    if( $product->is_type('variable') && isset($_POST['generate_variations_skus']) ) {
        $parent_sku   = $product->get_sku();
        $children_ids = $product->get_children();
        $count        = 0;
        
        // Loop through the variations Ids
        foreach( $children_ids as $child_id ){
            $count++;

            // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
            $variation = wc_get_product($child_id);
            
            // Set the prefix length based on variations count
            $prefix = sizeof($children_ids) < 100 ? sprintf('%02d', $count) : sprintf('%03d', $count);

            // Generate and set the sku
            $variation->set_sku( $parent_sku . '-' . $prefix );

            // Save variation
            $variation->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

a) On Variable products "Advanced" Tab settings: Check the checkbox

[image]

b) Update the  Variable product:

[image]

c) Now the SKUs numbers of All variations have been generated *(keeping the order)*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: WOW, thank you very much. Both solutions are very helpful. Perfect!

Comment: Hey LoicTheAztec, can I ask you anoher question?

now we have 
Parent SKU for exaple: 1111
Variation SKU is for example: 89 (changes from Variaton to variotan) . We want in front end: 1111-89

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting, it does not do linebreaks here.<br/><br/>So basically a combination ( and add a "-" in beetween): parentSKU-varSKU<br/><br/> Thank you for help